# apt-get download with version constraint

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to use `apt-get download` to fetch a specific version of a `.deb` file, but not necessarily the exact version. `.deb` dependencies are allowed to use expressions such as `>=0.3.0` and I would like `apt-get download` to fetch the same version as the one that would be downloaded using such dependency.

Summing it up, what I want to work is this:

```
$ apt-get download package='>=0.3.0'
```

Any idea how I could get that functionality?

Comment: Why don't you just manually download the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com?

Comment: Because I need to be sure that the package downloaded is the exact same package that would be downloaded when "apt-get install" is executed. I'm incorporating this in a cmake extension script.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by first finding out which version is the newest version that is also greater than or equal to your desired minimum version. Then, you download exactly that version using `apt-get download`. Here's a script that does this (it's a bit ugly, but you get the idea):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <packagename> <minimum version>"
    exit 1
fi

pkgname="$1"
minversion="$2"

V="0"

for version in `apt-cache madison $pkgname | awk -F'|' '{print $2}'`; do
    echo "Considering $version"
    if dpkg --compare-versions $version ge $minversion; then
        echo "- Version is at least $minversion"
        if dpkg --compare-versions $version gt $V; then
            echo "- This is the newest version so far"
            V=$version
        else
            echo "- We already have a newer version"
        fi
    else
        echo "- This is older than $minversion"
    fi
done

if [ "$V" = "0" ]; then
    echo "There is no version greater than or equal to $minversion"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Selected version: $V"

echo "Downloading"
apt-get download $pkgname=$V
echo "Done"
```

You'd have to add error checking in case the package doesn't exist, etc. but this contains the core solution. Also, I've assumed here that you want the newest available package that is at least a certain version. If you would instead like the oldest available package that is at least a certain version, you have to adjust the script to stop searching once it's found something that is at least your desired version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want exactly what `apt-get install` would give you, it might be worthwile to run `apt-get install` in 'download-only mode' using a custom archives directory:

```
-d, --download-only
  Download only; package files are only retrieved, not unpacked or installed.
  Configuration Item: APT::Get::Download-Only.
```

How to change the archives directory? This is a configuration option:

```
FILES
  [...]

  /var/cache/apt/archives/
  Storage area for retrieved package files. Configuration Item: Dir::Cache::Archives.
```

Those can be changed temporarily with the `--option` parameter:

```
-o, --option
  Set a Configuration Option; This will set an arbitrary configuration option. 
  The syntax is -o Foo::Bar=bar.  -o and --option can be used multiple times 
  to set different options.
```

To summarize:

```
apt-get install -d -o dir::cache::archives="/some/cache/dir" <package>
```

This command will download (and only download, not install) the relevant `.deb` files for `<package>` to `/some/cache/dir`. The directory will contain the `.deb` files for the package, its dependencies,  a lock file and 'partial' directory (which should be empty). Filtering out the exact `.deb` file you need should be trivial.

Comment: Unfortunately, `apt-get install` requires superuser access.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get download` also allows you to set target release. Wouldn't it help?

```
apt-get download package/testing
```

Comment to [#1](https://superuser.com/questions/577276/apt-get-download-with-version-constraint/578512#578512https://superuser.com/ques) (cannot use comments) - adding parameter `--print-uris` to `apt-get install` does not require root rights (but you have to download it itself – best with wget -i FILE_LIST).

Comment: Mikolaj Radwan seems to be looking for a way to fetch specific versions possibly using expressions for later script usage. This would just allow the download of the current package.

Answer (score 0):

Without SU privs you can still run apt-cache and combine with filtering to get that info.  Use something like:

On Debian 5:

```
apt-cache show <pkg> | head | grep -i version
```

On 6 you can use:

```
apt-cache show <pkg> | tail | grep -i version
```

Apt-cache seems to have changed behavior in the ordering of the list between 5 and 6 so that on 6 the newest one comes last.

One word of caution is that if you are using this output as you say "to fetch the same version as the one that would be downloaded using such dependency", the version of the package available may change if you run apt-get update (with su privs of course), or if that has been set to automatically run and happens in between when you gathered the version, and when you run the script that installs things expecting that to be the version.